# How to locate assosiated files to add and save css background-image to div tag

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

i am trying to add a background image to a div tag which is in a joomla custom html module responsible for the drop down menu in the t3 mega menu.
have located div tag using firefox developer tools.

div class="nav-child dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu"

would like to change to:

div class="nav-child dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu
 style="background-image: url('/images/headers/button_background.png')"

but i cannot find associated file/s to save changes to remote host. 
please help.

Comment: If your site is online, give me the address, so i will say you which file you must change.

Comment: wavelengths-hair.com

Answer (score 0):

Before any change **make a backup copy** from Bootstrap.css in this location:

> /components/com_eshop/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

You can do this by edit **Bootstrap.css** file, Firstly copy the image 'button_background.png' in the same folder (Where Bootstrap.css is). Then open the Bootstrap.css file, and add this style:

```
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    background-image: url(button_background.png) !important  /*only image name this case*/
}
```

Comment: yes thanks but which file should i add the changes to.

Comment: What you mean which file? you must have an image at the location and the address will be true... And one thing: in this line you wrote: `div class="nav-child dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu` after the menu you must have a `"` . `div class="nav-child dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu"`

Comment: Thank you both very much for the assistance its a great help and everything is working as intended. Neil Robertson's answer seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing files directly (and losing changes when Joomla or third party extensions are updated), it is probably better to implement this change using a CSS override.

It looks like you are using a T3 template so [add a custom.css file in the template CSS folder](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120) with the following code or similar:

```
.nav-child.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu {
  background-image: url('/images/headers/button_background.png');
}
```